# How to change the element at a specific index for all sub-lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list like this: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

I want to change it to `[[1, None, 3], [4, None, 6]]` using list comprehension.

I have tried:

```
print(list(x[1] = None for x in [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
```

Which throws the error `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="`.

I also tried:

```
print(list(x1 for x in [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] for x1 in x))
```

but this just gives `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

I have been thinking for like 1 hour, anyone know how to change my code output to `[[1, None, 3], [4, None, 6]]`?

Comment: may be `[[x, None, y] for x,_,y in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]`?

Comment: The way you do this will depend on how your data are organised. If the sub-lists are always comprised of exactly 3 values then it's straightforward. But what if the sub-lists vary in length. What would you want then? I'm also pleased to say that I've never had an error thrown into my face

Comment: To make it clear, is your question: *"How to change the middle item of each sub-list in a nested list to `None`"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data shown in the question is a list comprised of 2 sub-lists each of 3 elements.

Let's assume that it's the second value in each sub-list that should be substituted with None and that the sub-lists might vary in length. In that case:

```
_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

new_list = [[x, None, *y] for x, _, *y in _list]

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, None, 3], [4, None, 6]]
```

Now let's change the data to:

```
_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

...then the same list comprehension would generate:

```
[[1, None, 3], [4, None, 6, 7]]
```

**Note:**

This will fail if any sub-list contains fewer than 2 elements

Comment: thank you so much, after i saw your answer i think the code that i wanted is :
```
print(list([x,None,y] for x,_,y in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In code that should be:

```
[[None if i==1 else v for i,v in enumerate(l)] for l in [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]]
```

This of course creates a new list

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
[[a, None, c] for a,b,c in l]
#[[1, None, 2], [4, None, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the original list in-place:

```py
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for sub in l:
    sub[1] = None
print(l)
# [[1, None, 3], [4, None, 6]]
```

Comment: Of course this is functionally correct inasmuch as it produces the desired output. However, OP specifically (for no apparent reason) wants to use a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested list comprehension structure

```
[[k[i] if i != 1 else None for i in range(len(k))] for k in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]
# [[1, None, 3], [4, None, 6]]
```